# Why There Is No Database File

Tags: android, database, sqliteopenhelper

When I Run My App I Don't See Any Database File In Dir >> Android >> Data >> packagename....
And Also There Is No Crash Or Error:

My dpopenhelper Class:

```
public class dbopenhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static final String dbname = "dbtest";
   public static final String tblname = "tblname";

   public static final String cid = "id";
   public static final String cquestion = "queston";
   public static final String canswe = "answer";

   public static final String createtbl = "CREATE TABLE "+ tblname +"("+cid+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+cquestion+" TEXT,"+canswe+" TEXT);";

   public dbopenhelper(Context context) {
      super(context, dbname, null, 1);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

      db.execSQL(createtbl);

   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

   }
}
```

And In My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private dbopenhelper dbm;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      dbm = new dbopenhelper(this);
      dbm.getWritableDatabase();
   }
}
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you mean. If you mean that using a file explorer app on your android device, you cannot see the contents of your app's space then that is to be expected. The space is private to you app only.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access from an emulator or real device....
real device would need to be rooted so as to access the data directory that has the db file
but I guess you could try to use `getDatabasePath("your_db_name")` in the app to return the file object then use `getAbsolutePath()`  to get accurate path and try navigating to that path and if u see the file, rename it adding the .db3 extension and access it in SQLiteExplorer